# Issue with relative file path resolving in Saxon implementation of EXPath file library

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I want to use EXPath file library's `read-binary()` function in Saxon-EE 9.7.0.15.

When calling the function with the file absolute path, everything is working fine; but, when I try to use the relative path, e.g. `<xsl:variable name="binary" select="file:read-binary('../graphic/image.png', 16, 8)" as="xs:base64Binary"/>`, Saxon can't find the file and issue the following error message:

```
"file:not-found: No file exists at..."
```

File Module 1.0 documentation says that :

> An implementation must accept absolute and relative UNIX/Linux and
>   Windows paths as well as absolute file URIs. Some examples:
>
> C:\Test Dir\my file.xml: An absolute path on Windows platforms.
>
> /Test Dir/my file.xml: An absolute path on UNIX-based platforms.
>
> C:\\Test Dir//\my file.xml: An absolute path on Windows platforms
>   that tolerates an arbitrary number of slashes and backslashes.
>
> my file.xml: A relative path, pointing to a file in the current
>   working directory.
>
> file:///C:/Test%20Dir/my%20file.xml: An absolute file URI on Windows
>   platforms.
>
> file:///Test%20Dir/my%20file.xml: An absolute path on UNIX-based
>   platforms.

Is it a syntax problem? Is the function working directory different from my stylesheet directory?

Many thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Is "file:not-found: No file exists at..." the complete error message_ How do you run Saxon? If you run from the command line try whether the `-t` option shows you exactly which file it tries to load.

Comment: Try also what `file:current-dir()` outputs to check whether the right directory is searched.

Comment: Brillant idea! `file:current-dir()` output is  C:\Program Files\Oxygen XML Editor 19\. I guess there's no easy way to change the default directory from which relatives paths are resolved? Should I report it to Saxonica?

Comment: Ask in the oXygen forum if you use Saxon in the oXygen editor and it is set up to use the oXygen program directory, perhaps they can tell you how to change a setting or they consider fixing it in a future release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martin suggested the `fn:resolve-uri` function did the trick. The following code is working fine:

```
<xsl:variable name="binary" select="file:read-binary(resolve-uri('../graphic/cady_1.png'), 16, 8)" as="xs:base64Binary"/>
```

As Saxon documentation says:

> Functions in the EXPath file module use file paths that by default are
>   relative to the current working directory. However, if the Java system
>   property expath.base.directory is set, this will be used in preference
>   to the current working directory.

So EXPATH functions can't resolve paths that are relative to the stylesheet.

In oXygen 19.0 Java system property expath.base.directory seems to be set to oXygen installation directory.

Answer (score 1):

Just after the piece that you quoted, the spec says:

The function `file:base-dir` can be used to resolve file operations against the directory of the base URI:

```
let $filename := "input.txt"
let $dir := file:base-dir()
let $path := concat($dir, $filename)
return file:read-text($path)
```

So if you want to read a binary file relative to the location of the stylesheet, use, for example:

```
file:read-binary(file:base-dir() || '../graphic/image.png', 16, 8)
```

Comment: In fact, file:base-dir() || '../graphic/image.png' doesn't totally solve the problem: the file:basic-dir() return an URI, so it can't be directly concatenated with an relative path. I thought I could use file:resolve-path() but it's also resolving relatives paths from oXygen directory.

Comment: Try to throw in https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-resolve-uri into the mix and I think doing `resolve-uri(file:base-dir(), ''../graphic/image.png'')` should allow you to resolve your relative URI `'../graphic/image.png'` against the base URI.

Comment: Unfortunately the EXPath file spec isn't always clear about when file-names are expected (or returned), and when URIs are expected (or returned). And I suspect the Saxon implementation isn't always clear either. For example it says file:parent(static-base-uri()) returns the same as file:base-dir(), but file:parent expects a filename while static-base-uri() returns a URI. All very muddled.